# comparing $variables to achieve a score

Tags: php

Okay, this is screwing my head up. Mainly because I'm throwing myself in the deep end.

In short; players bet against the house playing "flower poker" ( with fun money ) I've got everything required to show the results as in, full house, two of a kind etc etc.. But I cannot assign a variable to control the score of what the user gets, and what the house gets. Thus not being able to compare them to update their fun money through mySQL.

What I have so far. This compares the randoms from the next part to give the results.

```
function counting(array $array) {
// Input figures
//print_r($array);

// Run the figures twice through the bucket-counter
$firstBuckets = bucketCounter($array);
$secondBuckets = bucketCounter($firstBuckets);

// Ignore counts of 1
array_shift($secondBuckets);

// Output, just need to do the lookup now
//echo ' converts to ';
//print_r($secondBuckets);
//echo "<br />";
//Lookup Table
if ($secondBuckets[0] == 1 && $secondBuckets[1] == 0) {
    echo ' One Pair';
} else if ($secondBuckets[0] == 2) {
    echo ' Two Pair';
} else if ($secondBuckets[1] == 1 && $secondBuckets[0] == 0) {
    echo ' Three of a kind';
} else if ($secondBuckets[0] == 1 && $secondBuckets[1] == 1) {
    echo ' Full House';
} else if ($secondBuckets[2] == 1) {
    echo ' Four of a kind';
} else if ($secondBuckets[3] == 1) {
    echo ' Five of a kind';
}

}
function counting1(array $array) {
// Input figures
//print_r($array);

// Run the figures twice through the bucket-counter
$firstBuckets = bucketCounter($array);
$secondBuckets = bucketCounter($firstBuckets);

// Ignore counts of 1
array_shift($secondBuckets);

// Output, just need to do the lookup now
//echo ' converts to ';
//print_r($secondBuckets);
//echo "<br />";
//Lookup Table

if ($secondBuckets[0] == 1 && $secondBuckets[1] == 0) {
    echo ' One Pair';
} else if ($secondBuckets[0] == 2) {
    echo ' Two Pair';
} else if ($secondBuckets[1] == 1 && $secondBuckets[0] == 0) {
    echo ' Three of a kind';
} else if ($secondBuckets[0] == 1 && $secondBuckets[1] == 1) {
    echo ' Full House';
} else if ($secondBuckets[2] == 1) {
    echo ' Four of a kind';
} else if ($secondBuckets[3] == 1) {
    echo ' Five of a kind';
}

}
/**
 * Bucket counter
*/
function bucketCounter(array $array) {
$result = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, );
foreach($array as $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
        $result[$value - 1]++;
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

This is what happens after they press the bet button.

```
    if (isset($_POST['play'])) {
    $rand1 = rand(1, 5);$rand2 = rand(1, 5);$rand3 = rand(1, 5);$rand4 = rand(1, 5);$rand5 = rand(1, 5);$rand6 = rand(1, 5);$rand7 = rand(1, 5);$rand8 = rand(1, 5);$rand9 = rand(1, 5);$rand10 = rand(1, 5);
    if ($_POST['bet'] <= $user_data['coins']) {
        if ($_POST['bet'] < 999999999) {
            if ($_POST['bet'] > 0.99) {
                if ($user_data['coins'] > 1) {
                    //$userscore = 0;
                    //$hostscore = 0;
                    //echo $rand1.', '.$rand2.', '.$rand3.', '.$rand4.', '.$rand5;
                    echo '<font size="2">You\'ve planted : <br></font>';
                    if ($rand1 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand1 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand1 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand1 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand1 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand2 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand2 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand2 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand2 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand2 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand3 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand3 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand3 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand3 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand3 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand4 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand4 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand4 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand4 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand4 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand5 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand5 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand5 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand5 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand5 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}                     
                    //echo '<br>';
                    counting(array($rand1, $rand2, $rand3, $rand4, $rand5));
                    echo ' '.$userscore;
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<font size="2">Host planted : <br></font>';
                    if ($rand6 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand6 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand6 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand6 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand6 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand7 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand7 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand7 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand7 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand7 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand8 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand8 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand8 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand8 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand8 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand9 === 1) {     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand9 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand9 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand9 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand9 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}
                    if ($rand10 === 1){     echo '<img src="images/Red_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand10 === 2) {echo '<img src="images/Blue_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand10 === 3) {echo '<img src="images/Yellow_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand10 === 4) {echo '<img src="images/Orange_flowers.png">';} else if ($rand10 === 5) {echo '<img src="images/Flowers_(pastel).png">';}                     
                    //echo '<br>';
                    counting1(array($rand6, $rand7, $rand8, $rand9, $rand10));
                    echo '<br>';
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

If I try to set the $userscore in counting & set the $hostscore in counting1 functions it doesn't allow me to access it in the 2nd code box therefore I cannot compare the scores and rule a winner.

Comment: Edit: this isn't fixed, I still cannot set $userscore or $hostscore if I try to set it in the //lookup tables it still can't be accessed outside of the function.

Comment: Think before question

Comment: I still haven't fixed it. I thought by doing that it would have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access those variables because of the thing called "[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)".

But in your case overcoming that obstacle is very easy, you functions just need to return values.

So, assuming you will assign $score variable, you just need to add

```
return $score;
```

as the last line in your function.

Then in your second code box - change

```
counting(array($rand1, $rand2, $rand3, $rand4, $rand5));
```

to

```
$userscore = counting(array($rand1, $rand2, $rand3, $rand4, $rand5));
```

And then do the same thing for the $hostscore.

Actually, you do not even need two functions to count user and host score separately. Leave just one and call it two times like that:

```
$userscore = counting(array($rand1, $rand2, $rand3, $rand4, $rand5));
$hostscore = counting(array($rand6, $rand7, $rand8, $rand9, $rand10));
```